# Probability Generating Function for Geometric using conditioning

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation, probability-generating-fn

I was wondering if someone could look over my derivation of the probability generating function for geometric RV. I think I arrived at the right conclusions. I wanted to take the alternate route over the infinite sum derivation.

Let $X$ be geometric with parameter $p$.

And let $Y = 1$ if you have success on the first trial and $Y = 0$ otherwise, then:

$E(t^X) = E[E(t^X|Y)] = E(t^X|Y=0)P(Y=0) + E(t^X|Y=1)P(Y=1)$

$= E(t^{1+X'})(1-p) + E(t^{1})p$

Note that $X$ and $X'$ are identically distributed $(E(t^X) = E(t^{X'}))$ and so:

$E(t^X) = tE(t^{X'})(1-p) + tp$

$E(t^X)[1-t(1-p)] = tp$ and so:

$G_X(t) = E(t^X) = \frac{tp}{1-t(1-p)}$ for $X$ geometric with paramter $p$